# Align mathematics equation in a box

Tags: align, framed

I have the following code of maths equation in a box :

```
\begin{framed}
\begin{align*}
&C_\star \rightarrow E_\star :  &x=3\dfrac{5\phi^2+24\phi+12v+24}{\phi^2}, &y=108\dfrac{-\phi^3+5\phi^2+2\phi v+12\phi+4v+8}{\phi^3}\\
&E_\star \rightarrow C_\star :  &\phi=12\dfrac{6-x}{6x-y-198}, &v=2\dfrac{x^3-18x^2+3267x-324y-71658}{x^3+36x^2-12xy-5643x+396y+84834}
\end{align*}
\end{framed}
```

Everything is fine except that `x` and `\phi` is not aligned. Is there anything wrong with the code as I want to make sure `x` aligns with `\phi` and `y` aligns with `v`.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doubling ampersands gives the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}    


\begin{framed}
\begin{align*}
&C_\star \rightarrow E_\star :  &&x=3\dfrac{5\phi^2+24\phi+12v+24}{\phi^2}, &&y=108\dfrac{-\phi^3+5\phi^2+2\phi v+12\phi+4v+8}{\phi^3}\\
&E_\star \rightarrow C_\star :  &&\phi=12\dfrac{6-x}{6x-y-198}, &&v=2\dfrac{x^3-18x^2+3267x-324y-71658}{x^3+36x^2-12xy-5643x+396y+84834}
\end{align*}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps give any insight why and how a double ampersand behaves differently from a single one?

Answer (score 3):

You possibly want to have a look at `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry} % or whatever options
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{alignat*=3}
&C_\star \rightarrow E_\star
  &{}: x&=3\dfrac{5\phi^2+24\phi+12v+24}{\phi^2},\quad
  &    y&=108\dfrac{-\phi^3+5\phi^2+2\phi v+12\phi+4v+8}{\phi^3}\\
&E_\star \rightarrow C_\star
  &{}: \phi&=12\dfrac{6-x}{6x-y-198},\quad
  &    v&=2\dfrac{x^3-18x^2+3267x-324y-71658}{x^3+36x^2-12xy-5643x+396y+84834}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]